# Visual Studio template isn't copying files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, project-template

I created a multi-project template and it seems to be working for the most part except for one major thing: it isn't copying the files in the template directory over to the new project.

[image]

In the image, I'm showing one of the projects that is created as part of the template (result on the left is DAS.Test.CQRS.Command). All of the files are listed there but only one of them is being copied into the new project. During project creation, Visual Studio is outputting "Project created successfully" and I don't see any errors in the output window. I have confirmed that all of the files are located within the template zip file inside of their project subdirectories.

[image]

I'm not sure what other threads to pull on. Any ideas? I apologize for the photos, but there's a lot to show.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @M4rtini no I didn't. Sometimes it would work, sometimes it wouldn't. I moved on to dotnet CLI templates which are way better anyway for a number of a reasons. No problems there.